# Would it be considered as a sin If I say something blasphemous in my head by mistake?

Tags: halal-haram

Like for example, there is one movie's name which is based on a type of afterlife the greeks believed in, which is in another religion. I said it in my head by mistake, and said it aloud. The name itself in the movie is used to refer to a space station, is it a sin? Did I do something haram?

Comment: If you said it by mistake then its ok, because Its unintentional, as you drink water or eat by mistake during fasting then your fast will not be broken. and if you sudden remember that you were fasting you have to spit out whatever is in your mouth otherwise your fast will be broken. the same way if you sudden got that you are doing wrong by mistake or unintentional the stop it quickly and do isteghfaar and repent to Allah.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam All The Sins And Rewards Are Based Upon Our Intentions...
If Someone Knows Any Thing That Is Not Good But S/He Does, Then He's Responsible For His Actions. As You Have Said That You Do Not Want To Say That Word But In The Mind You Just Whispered It UnIntentionally Then It Is All Ok. 
By The Way Make Istighfaar Recitation In  Your Daily Routine And Do Try To Ignore All The Stuff That Make You Think Blasphemous Un Or intentionally.
ALLAH Bless You.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what blasphemy you are referring to, but this is what I believe. As long as it is in your head, it is not a sin unless you talk about it. In simple words, you should not have shared that you said something blasphemous in your head.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE, Please go through [How to write a good answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Specifically, the part that talks about providing islamic sources for your answer.

Comment: Proof, I think that was a mistranslation in the hadith, you read. In other versions, I think it said it's only sin if you say it verbally, not if you talk about it.

Comment: It is not from a hadith. I believe this to be true because it makes sense to me.